# Can't use GNOME Shell extensions due to "error parsing schema" 

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I get this error in the gnome-tweak-tool konsole dialog

```
CRITICAL: Error parsing schema org.gnome.shell (/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.gschema.xml)
```

And then a series of other errors which state 'unknown extension error'.

All of the extensions show, but none of them can be switched on. Any ideas?

Comment: konsole??? are you using kde?

Answer (score 1):

Using konsole has nothing to do with this.

Changed the files as mentioned in the article below:

- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gsettings.py`

Now have full access to all shell extensions. A few don't work (alt+tab one for example) but they are all accessible, and there is no longer an error from `gnome-tweak-tool`.

## Steps

Replace lines 48-61 of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py`:

```
class GnomeShell:

EXTENSION_STATE = {
    "ENABLED"       :   1,
    "DISABLED"      :   2,
    "ERROR"         :   3,
    "OUT_OF_DATE"   :   4
}

EXTENSION_TYPE = {
    "SYSTEM"        :   1,
    "PER_USER"      :   2
}
```

with these:

```
class GnomeShell:

EXTENSION_STATE = {
    "ENABLED"       :   1,
    "DISABLED"      :   2,
    "ERROR"         :   3,
    "OUT_OF_DATE"   :   4,
    "DISABLED"      :   6
}

EXTENSION_TYPE = {
    "SYSTEM"        :   1,
    "PER_USER"      :   2
}
```

This should get all extensions working.

Lastly, to clear up the remaining errors, replace lines 44-52 of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gsettings.py`:

```
                        #summary is compulsory, description is optional
                    summary = key.getElementsByTagName("summary")[0].childNodes[0].data
                    try:
                        description = key.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].data
                    except:
                        description = ""
                    self._schema[key.getAttribute("name")] = {
                            "summary"       :   summary,
                            "description"   :   description
                    }
```

with these:

```
                        #summary is compulsory, description is optional
                    try:
                        summary = key.getElementsByTagName("summary")[0].childNodes[0].data
                        description = key.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].data
                    except:
                        description = ""
                        summary = "No Summary"
                    self._schema[key.getAttribute("name")] = {
                            "summary"       :   summary,
                            "description"   :   description
                    }
```

([Ubuntu Forums source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874010))

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me.  I have changed both files exactly as stated with proper indentation yet I still receive the unknown extension error.  Any ideas?