# Can't enable GNOME Shell extensions

Tags: 11.10, gnome, extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I recently installed the `Media player indicator` extension and all the extensions are blocked. I cannot enable the ones that have been disabled earlier. I also tried to disable one of those which were enabled and restarted using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and when I started `Advanced settings` that extension was unable to start along the others.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aduy8.png]

Please see the output of running `gnome-tweak-tool` in a terminal [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/730345/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to
[11.10 - Can't use GNOME Shell extensions due to "error parsing schema" - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73620/cant-use-gnome-shell-extensions-due-to-error-parsing-schema),
and [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874010).

Follow the links for instructions

Comment: Could you please include some information in your post rather than only linking?