# How can I enable Gnome Shell Extensions with Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I am having a problem similar to that asked (and solved) here: [Can't enable GNOME Shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76072/cant-enable-gnome-shell-extensions).  I have performed both of the "tweaks" explained in that solution (i.e., [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73620/cant-use-gnome-shell-extensions-due-to-error-parsing-schema) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874010)); but that does not seem to help.

My gnome-shell is version 3.2.1.  When I run gnome-tweak-tool from a shell, I get the following output:

> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> CRITICAL: Unknown extension error
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
>
> (gnome-tweak-tool:7823): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed

Has anyone actually solved this besides to the references above?  I have made the suggested modifications from those sites.

Comment: Does gnome-tweak-tool start ? The error messages you are posting are quite meaningless. 2. Do you have any additional ppa's enabled ? if yes, which ones' ?

Comment: Yes, it starts.  The messages are displayed while starting... but, from the Shell Extensions panel, only User Themes Extension and Applications Menu Extension are usable.  The other 9 extensions have an error (orange) icon displayed and they are disabled.  The screen looks just the same as displayed in the attached link:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/76072/cant-enable-gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: which ppa 's do you have enabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.  I re-visited the "solutions" from the [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76072/cant-enable-gnome-shell-extensions) and un-did the changes which I had earlier made per that posting... and, although gnome-tweak-tool still reports:

> CRITICAL: Error parsing schema org.gnome.shell (/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.gschema.xml)

the extensions are enabled.